# preg_match() Error after Wordpress Update to latest in class-wp-block-parser.php

Tags: php, wordpress

After updating to wordpress latest version (5.3.2) an error shows as follows.

Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home1/myinterior/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-block-parser.php on line 417

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home1/myinterior/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-block-parser.php on line 489

All the plugins are up to date.

Any solution to fix this issue?...
Thanks.

im also stuck on this, I cant understand why? I shouldnt need to worry about cored wp files right?